# Extract arbitrary rectangular patches from image in python

Tags: python, image, numpy

Is there a way to extract a rectangle of my choice from an image, maybe using numpy arrays?
Most implementations available seem to be for regular sliding window solutions, but those always include steps, or rectangles of the same aspect ratio, or something like that.

Is it possible to provide the beginning x and y coordinates and the width and height (or ending x and y coordinates), and extract exactly that rectangle? Can this be done using numpy arrays alone? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: In what format are your images?

Comment: They were originally jpeg images and I've converted them into numpy arrays.

Comment: What exactly do you mean my extract, select 3 points manually? And what should your output look like?

Comment: By extract I mean for eg if I have a 360x240 image, and I want to extract a rectangle with starting point (10,10) and size (100,200), then the output should be a 100x200 sub-image which starts from x=10 and y=10. Not manually, I'll be providing the patch particulars in the code.

Comment: Do you mean something like rect  =  np.copy(image[10:110, 10:210])

Comment: @Alfe maybe... but what patch coordinates would translate into your code? Would the starting and ending coordinates be (4,2) and (8,5), so that the rectangle has width:4 and height:2?

Comment: Use the double index as provided by @jrsm.  That's your solution I guess.

Comment: @jrsm that worked! If you put it as an answer instead of the comments I'll select it as the answer.

Comment: I've tried a few combinations of this but I don't seem to be getting the image patches I'm expecting. In this syntax,  **np.copy(image[a:b, c:d])**, can you please clarify what *a,b,c, and d* are in terms of ending and starting x and y coordinates and width and height?

Comment: Okay I've got it. it's **np.copy(img[y1:y1+height,x1:x1+width])**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do this would be slicing i.e.

```
rect = np.copy(img[y1:y1+height,x1:x1+width])
```

where (x1, y1) is the upper left corner of your rectangle.